# Can't "SaveDC" and "RestoreDC" function be used in different message processing code?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I try to set my preferred device context properties in `WM_CREATE` message and then use it in `WM_PAINT` message. My method is to use `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` function in `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT` message respectively. But the result doesn't meet my need. What I really need is to show a circle in the center of the client area.

```c
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin") ;
     HWND         hwnd ;
     MSG          msg ;
     WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

     wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
     wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
     wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
     wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
     wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
     wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
     wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
     wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

     if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
     {
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows NT!"), 
                      szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
          return 0 ;
     }

     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,                  // window class name
                          TEXT ("The Hello Program"), // window caption
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x size
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y size
                          NULL,                       // parent window handle
                          NULL,                       // window menu handle
                          hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                          NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

     ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
     UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
          TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
          DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
     }
     return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     HDC         hdc ;
     PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
     RECT rect;
     static int nSavedDC;

     switch (message)
     {          
     case WM_CREATE:
         hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
         SetMapMode(hdc, MM_LOMETRIC);
         GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
         SetViewportOrgEx(hdc, rect.right/2, rect.bottom/2, NULL);
         nSavedDC = SaveDC(hdc);         //I want to save the current state of device context to be used in WM_PAINT message.
         ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
         return 0;

     case WM_PAINT:
          hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          RestoreDC(hdc, nSavedDC);       //Restore the the state of device context which is saved in WM_CREATE message.
          Ellipse(hdc, -100, 100, 100, -100);
          EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
          return 0 ;

     case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage (0) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Comment: This code will never work. You can't call `ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);`; the appropriate call would be `ReleaseDC(hwnd, nSavedDc);`, which of course would be meaningless. Why do you think you need to `SaveDC` in `WM_CREATE` in the first place? There is zero use in the code you've written for any reasonable purpose, so what exactly do you think you're accomplishing here? What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: This isn't how DCs work. You're technically supposed to manually load the DC with its state each time, because you aren't guaranteed to get the same DC each time — they're in a pool, or something like that. (There are ways to demand a specific DC for each window, but those are holdovers from 16-bit Windows that have lots of pitfalls nowadays that can produce spectacular results in sufficiently complicated programs.) Raymond Chen has a lot on the subject. Just load your state each time you call `BeginPaint()` or `GetDC()` and reset it before undoing that.

Comment: @KenWhite `ReleaseDC(hwnd, nSavedDc);` is completely wrong as `nSavedDc` is an integer. The original `ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);` code is correct.

Comment: You cannot save one dc and restore it to another. Furthermore, saving and restoring [is stack-like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162929(v=vs.85).aspx), but you aren't using it as a stack.

Comment: It looks like what you want is `CS_OWNDC`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks error handling. You need to inspect all the values returned by each GDI function call.

As described on [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162946(v=vs.85).aspx) the purpose of `SaveDC` / `RestoreDC` is mostly to restore state to original after you finish drawing. And this is exactly what you aren't doing in both `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT` message handlers. You always leave DC in modified state.

As for using `SaveDC` / `RestoreDC` to set up DC state once and then quickly restore it at every paint operation instead of setting up from scratch every time I think of at least one obstacle: If some other function calls `RestoreDC` in between handlers DC restoring item that wasn't on top of the DC states stack then your saved state that was on top of the stack will get destroyed as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162929(v=vs.85).aspx).